# How do I handwrite 小心翼翼 well?

Tags: handwriting

My handwriting (of 他小心翼翼地把邮票揭下来):

> [image: my handwritten 他小心翼翼地把邮票揭下来]

The 小心翼翼 looks horribly imbalanced: there's two sparse characters 小心 followed by two dense characters 翼翼. I'm wondering what I can do to make it look better.

**Question**: How do I handwrite 小心翼翼 well?

*Note*: I'm not asking for generic handwriting tips.  Answers should answer the specific question *How do I handwrite 小心翼翼 well?*  One possible way of answering this question would be to include your own (properly) handwritten 小心翼翼 and explain how it differs from the one I supplied.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed I wrote 邮 backwards.  Anyway...

Comment: Just make each character about the same size. 翼翼 is obviously bigger than all other characters

Comment: The lower right part of your 揭 is problematic as well. The handwriting however I think is fine.

Comment: You can practice first by writing it good in the size you can write it good at, then slower write it smaller and smaller.

Comment: I would recommend [書法字典](http://www.shufazidian.com/), an online calligraphy dictionary. Though, not many Chinese people actually practice handwriting nowadays—especially, in a traditional calligraphy way (:sad:).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should write hanzi "**横平竖直**" and "**有棱有角**".
Second, you can correct the structure of the word "心". Usually, we don't handwrite it like that. [image]

Third, you can zoom out the word "翼".
Hope these are useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

When Chinese child learn to write 汉字，they usually use paper which with 田字格first. [image: 田字格] You should try to arrange the space, write a character in a 田 block. After you are familiar to write in it, you can write every character almost the same size.
Beside, in Chinese 书法, it is not the best way to write all character in same size, like this [image: 行书字帖]
I don't know why I can't see the image I uploaded, but you can search 田字格 and 行书字帖.

Comment: Beginners are best to practice from regular script(楷书).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a practice paper, "田字格" is very good.
2. You should practise "笔划" , then practise "汉字".  E.g.  before writing "小心翼翼", you should write 羽, 田, 共 hundreds/thousands of times. You should always remember: 一笔一划的写字. 不要连笔.
3. Once you have written Chinese characters a million times, then you will have your special feeling/intuition about how to write Chinese characters. And you have your own style of writing, which looks natural, pretty, and balanced.

Comment: Quote:- "once you wrote Chinese characters million times...." @Becky. Please be kind enough to show us your 翼翼 when you have written them a million times, assuming you are not too tired? :)

Comment: While the idea of writing 翼 a million times is amusing, it surely means writing Chinese characters in general.

Comment: not writing 翼 millions of times.  -_-!  this is waste of time. I mean all the chinese charactors you wrote , the total sum count is million.